# Select in ON DUPLICATE KEY with values Coming from Insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an INSERT statement with and SELECT Statement 'ON DUPLICATE Key'. I want the value of INSERT statements in the WHERE clause of SELECT statement.

Here is the Example i tried but unable to get the value of insert.

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (a, b, c), (a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = (SELECT c from table1 WHERE table1.a = VALUES(table2.a));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `VALUES()`.  You should specify your columns, so I think you want:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (a, b, c)
    VALUES (a, b, c),
           (a1, b1, c1),
           (a2, b2, c3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = VALUES(c);
```

Comment: No specifying column doesn’t make any difference. Problem is in select, when I use select ( select * from table1 ) the where clause does not recognise the values(c) of the insert. If I didn’t use Select the value(c) works.